# Cache same table twice in 2 dataframe Spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, caching, apache-spark-sql

I have cached a hive table into a dataframe in Spark.

Using a timer, I have scheduled the caching again after 2 hours, and store into different dataframe. But this time, the caching doesn't work as I expected it to. It seems like it did not cache the table as I was monitoring the logs and the free Ram available.

Purpose - I have a static variable dataframe pointing to the cached data. Now, after 2 hours, I want to refresh the cache, and then point that variable to this new cache, and unpersist the old one. If the second caching fails, I would not repoint.

Below is my code. Actually, the code is in java, hence it is Dataset instead of Dataframe.

```
private static Dataset<Row> dataset;
..
..
public void cacheDataset(SparkSession spark){

        String query = "select * from database.table";

        Dataset<Row> localDataset = spark.sql(query);
        localDataset.cache();

        long count = localDataset.count();
        System.out.println("Dataset is Cached. Count = " + count);

        Dataset<Row> previousDataset = dataset;

        this.dataset = localDataset;

        System.out.println("\n\nStarting to unpersist a dataset\n\n");
        try{
            previousDataset.unpersist();
        }catch (NullPointerException e){
            System.out.println("Received Null pointer Exception. It means it was the first caching");
        }

        System.out.println("\n\nUnpersisting completed\n\n");

    }
```

How can I cache the same table again into different dataset/dataframe (I am fine with double memory consumption here for some time), then repoint my variable to new cached set, and then remove the old caching to free the memory.

Comment: AFAIK `cache()` is a transformation. And that means that it should be chained in order to work. Try `Dataset<Row> localDataset = spark.sql(query).cache();` instead of cache on different line

Comment: Cache on a separate line is fine, it's not a transformation.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't cached previousDataset, you cached localDataset. Think of previousDataset as a new dataset with the identity transformation applied to it. If you try to unpersist localDataset it should work.